# Not Working creation of the variable using malloc

Tags: c++, curl, ftp, dev-c++

I want to create the program with **C++** and this login on my **server FTP** and occurs if there is a new file in the folder of server.

My friend already created this program, it is functioning (working) and passes it to me .

Inside the program we using the library and tools of CURL for login on FTP.

On my computer this program not working using DEV C++.
Then I create the new project, rewrite all code of old program, load the library of CURL and Compile.

The program get problem of executing.

Analyze the program there is an anomaly with **MALLOC**.

This is a code where is there a anomaly:

```
 char* userpwd = (char*)malloc(strlen(USERNAME)+1+strlen(PASSWORD));
 printf("\n malloc %s",userpwd);
          strcat(userpwd, (const char*)USERNAME);
          strcat(userpwd, ":");
          strcat(userpwd, (const char*)PASSWORD);
 printf("\n not %s",userpwd);
```

Explain how this function:
First, I have to build the variable that contain "USERNAME:PASSWORD".
The problem is after `char* userpwd = (char*)malloc(strlen(USERNAME)+1+strlen(PASSWORD));`
Because when I print the value of **userpwd**, I have **-** or other characters before the string.
Then is normal the login is incorrect or denied.

This is the image:
[image]

For function without problem, I can change the code:

```
char userpwd[50];
              userpwd="USERNAME";
              strcat(userpwd, ":");
              strcat(userpwd, "PASSWORD");
     printf("\n not %s",userpwd);
```

And this function.

But the program read the file `configuration.txt` for obtain the URL, USERNAME and PASSWORD.
Then is convenient to use `malloc` but in my computer and on my sister, I have the anomaly of characters.

**How can I prevent these anomalies? Why do I have these strange characters?**
Thanks for any help possible

**P.S:** I delete the string USERNAME and PASSWORD with colour white for protect my account.

Comment: u need a `memset` after `malloc`

Comment: Why are you faffing around with low-level memory in the first place? Just use `std::string` for your strings, and you'll have far fewer problems.

Comment: I know it but using pointers, the program will be lighter and faster. @MikeSeymour
Please how can use memset after malloc? SakthiKumar

Comment: The code you say has no problems won't even compile.

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani "lighter and faster"? 1: No, it won't. 2: How many times per second are you planning to log in, exactly?

Comment: I think infinite because is a project of video surveillance.
It must sound the alarm as he receives a movement "file" on the folder server.
(There is a webcam That upload a video file folder on the server)

Comment: "Infinite" times per second? Impressive!

Comment: Honestly, it's a total fallacy that introducing bugs with `malloc` and C-strings will make your program "lighter and faster". It's just not true. All it accomplishes is making your development slower.

Comment: Possibly (but unlikely) shaving a couple of nanoseconds off a string concatenation won't affect the time it takes to log in to an ftp site in a way that can be meaningfully measured. Remember that "lighter and faster" is the reasoning that ultimately caused Heartbleed to be so severe - it's a potentially disastrous habit to get into, especially when you're sending bits over a cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add 1 for the terminating zero.
You also forgot to zero-terminate the string before you `strcat` onto it.
That leads to undefined behaviour.

```
char* userpwd = (char*)malloc(strlen(USERNAME) + 1 + strlen(PASSWORD) + 1);
userpwd[0] = 0;
```

Or (better) use idiomatic C++:

```
std::string USERNAME;
std::string PASSWORD;
// Load username and password...

std::string pass = USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD;
```

and pass `pass.c_str()` to the login function

Comment: In an hour I change the code for try his answer.
Now it's time for lunch.

Comment: But I not see what are the causes of strange characters of malloc.

Comment: Ok In an hour I changing.

Comment: Thanks.
This function also without +1 final on `char* userpwd = (char*)malloc(strlen(USERNAME) + 1 + strlen(PASSWORD)°);`.
But now I have this +1 final.

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani No, it doesn't work without the +1 - it's undefined. You may not see any problems right now, but it's not a valid program, and anything can happen at any time if you run it.